# Can I add free space to Win7 partition in Ubuntu dual boot setup?

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

I'm not sure why this free space is there, but if I extend the Win7 partition to use the space, I get a warning that it may mess up my mbr. Obv not critical to fix this, but I like to keep things tidy. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Here is the warning from Gparted

[image: Here is the warning from Gparted]

Comment: Please use the image button and [edit] your question.  This will make sure your screenshot is visible to all users.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *extend* the Win7 partition, since this will overflow into the following
partition.

You need to move the Win7 partition up (left) to position it to the beginning of the
disk, so the free space will follow the partition, then you may resize it.

Note that Win7 cannot be moved while booting from it, so needs to be done when
booting from Ubuntu.

Note also that resizing Win7 should be done while booting from Windows and not
from Ubuntu.

Last note: Take careful backups before doing any partition work, just in case.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! What would you suggest as the best way to move the Win7 partition to the left from Ubuntu console (or GUI), while not messing up the MBR?

Comment: For a utility to use in Ubuntu, you could use GParted. The MBR message is a bit puzzling, since the MBR shouldn't be involved at all. I would really like you to add to your post the name of the disk utility you are using and a screenshot of the MBR error message, before you do anything. Let me know here when it's done.

Comment: Added screenshot above thanks

Comment: This seems like a standard warning about the dangers of moving partitions. The dangers do exist, so ensure you have very good backup before doing the move.

Comment: Moved Win7 with Gparted. Linux still boots. Win7 complains that it can't find a device. Put the intall disk in to Repair but it can't see my keyboard or mouse. Did some searches, tried USB settings in the bios and gave up. I never use Win7 anymore, and was thinking of just getting rid of it on this box anyway. Its probably just a liability.

Comment: Problems with Windows when booted from a repair disk are not related to operations on the hard disk. I hope you don't have any hardware problems that Linux somehow manages to avoid.